Pixel tablet in AS emulator is not loading the correct layout version
My app has different layout versions for 'port', 'land', 'SW600dp' etc., which load correctly into the emulator for other devices such as Pixel 7a and Pixel C, but the emulator for the Pixel Tablet only loads the base layout which does not fit correctly on the emulator in landscape mode. My development machine has SDK API 34 installed. Can I force the emulator to load the correct layout version?
